# PHP-FPM starts before the web folder mounts in /etc/fstab, throws error

Tags: php-fpm, fstab, runlevel

I'm running a LAEMP reverse proxy server on Arch in the cloud.

I have my `nextcloud/data` folder mounted to an attached storage drive at `/mnt/hdd/nextcloud/data`, linked to `/srv/www/nextcloud/data`.

If I don't do this, but keep `nextcloud/data` on the same disk as `/`, then I don't have this problem at all.

At `reboot`, the system starts; PHP pages get an error, but neither `httpd` nor `nginx` show any errors with `systemctl status`. The error is in `php-fpm`.

Output of `systemctl status php-fpm`:

```
× php-fpm.service - The PHP FastCGI Process Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/php-fpm.service; enabled; preset: disabled)
    Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/php-fpm.service.d
             └─override.conf
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2023-05-30 16:47:30 PDT; 14s ago
    Process: 316 ExecStart=/usr/bin/php-fpm --nodaemonize --fpm-config /etc/php/php-fpm.conf (code=exited, status=226/NAMESPACE)
   Main PID: 316 (code=exited, status=226/NAMESPACE)
        CPU: 8ms

May 30 16:47:29 MY_HOST systemd[1]: Starting The PHP FastCGI Process Manager...
May 30 16:47:29 MY_HOST (php-fpm)[316]: php-fpm.service: Failed to set up mount namespacing: /run/systemd/unit-root/mnt/hdd/nextcloud/data: No such file or directory
May 30 16:47:29 MY_HOST (php-fpm)[316]: php-fpm.service: Failed at step NAMESPACE spawning /usr/bin/php-fpm: No such file or directory
May 30 16:47:30 MY_HOST systemd[1]: php-fpm.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=226/NAMESPACE
May 30 16:47:30 MY_HOST systemd[1]: php-fpm.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 30 16:47:30 MY_HOST systemd[1]: Failed to start The PHP FastCGI Process Manager.
```

Nextcloud is getting this from `systemd` drop-in `/etc/systemd/system/php-fpm.service.d/override.conf` :

```
[Service]
...
ReadWritePaths=/srv/www/nextcloud/data
```

When I run `systemctl restart php-fpm`, the error goes away forever until the next reboot.

I presume that the `php-fpm` service can't find the `nextcloud` folder because `hdd/` isn't mounted when `php-fpm` starts and wants to look in its web folders. I would think that I should somehow adjust the run levels for `php-fpm` and/or (preferrably) when `/etc/fstab` loads the attached storage drive to `/mnt/hdd`.

`/etc/fstab` mounts the drive `/mnt/hdd` with this statement:

```
/dev/vdc1               /mnt/hdd       ext4    defaults,noatime,nofail 0 0
```

Nothing I search for on the Internet tells me how to solve this problem. Everything in the search results shows unrelated matters about `php-fpm` or `/etc/fstab`. Even then, at best I would get some script kiddy answer.

I want to know the proper way to have `vdc1` mount much earlier at runtime, or at least have `php-fpm` wait until the directory is available before throwing a fit.

Comment: Please show your systemd service drop in

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I added the drop-in for php-fpm

Comment: I seem to have mitigated this using monit, at least for the time being. But, the problem remains that a service starts before `/etc/fstab` can mount all drives.

Comment: Please show the output of `systemd-analyze critical-chain php-fpm.service`. And it looks like you omitted lines from the drop in file, please show it completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While [another answer](https://serverfault.com/a/1132366/487033) helped for a time with a statement inside `/etc/fstab`, modifying the `.service` file ended up being my more reliable solution...

We need [some statements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47297595/10343144) in the service config, but under `[Unit]`, not `[Service]`, somewhat like:

```
[Unit]
Requires=local-fs.target
After=local-fs.target
```

But, the question is where to put them and what the values should be for `Requires=` and `After=`.

We need a service [drop-in override config](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/systemd).

The service is `php-fpm`, with its original config file at `/lib/systemd/system/php-fpm.service`. However, modifying that is not persistent since it is replaced by upgrades. Instead, an override file needed to be made, with any name and the `.conf` extension in `/etc/systemd/system/php-fpm.service.d/`.  While `/etc/systemd/system/` should already exist with many things in it, the `php-fpm.service.d/` subfolder may need to be created.

Based on **/etc/fstab** :

```
UUID=long-uuid-serial-c0de1  /mnt/ssd       ext4    defaults,noatime,nofail,x-systemd.required-by=php-fpm.service 0 0 
UUID=long-uuid-serial-c0de2  /mnt/hdd       ext4    defaults,noatime,nofail,x-systemd.required-by=php-fpm.service 0 0
```

This [command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/247547/315069):

```bash
systemctl list-units --type=mount
```

returns many lines, including these:

```
  mnt-hdd.mount                 loaded active mounted /mnt/hdd
  mnt-ssd.mount                 loaded active mounted /mnt/ssd
```

which we recognize from `/etc/fstab` as `/mnt/hdd` and `/mnt/ssd`.

So, we need this file:

**/etc/systemd/system/php-fpm.service.d/mount.conf** :

```
[Unit]
Requires=mnt-hdd.mount
After=mnt-hdd.mount
Requires=mnt-ssd.mount
After=mnt-ssd.mount
```

Answer (score 3):

You can configure the systemd unit to be started only after the mounts by adding the following configuration options either to the existing drop in file, or by adding another one if you don't want to modify it:

```ini
[Unit]
After=local-fs.target
```

Another option would be to add the following option to the mount definition in fstab:

```
x-systemd.required-by=php-fpm.service
```

Comment: the `fstab` option worked like a charm!